# Parallel File Upload in php

Tags: php, multithreading, file-upload, parallel-processing

I am coding my own image hosting script.I think that parallel processing will definitely help to make full use of the hardware (CPU with multi cores , lots of ram) in a production environment when the user upload many images at one time.Size of images can be a maximum of 10mb.

How far i am correct about my assumption about parallel processing? How can i implement parallel processing or multi threading with php to make multiple file uploads more efficient

Comment: How about enqueuing your uploads into a table with a status flag and letting a cron job task take care of a certain amount of uploads at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

in PHP there is **no** "real" multi-threading. But you can help yourself out with extensions like pthreads.

Check this website out:

http://pthreads.org/